# Force and its components

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

Can anyone explain intuitively what actually are components of forces (in the $x,\,y,\,z$ directions)? Are they actual forces? Can the components have their own components in other directions?

Comment: When you have a force acting it is sometimes more convenient to think of that one force being made up oaf a number of forces which are called the components of that force. The reverse is also tue in that when you many forces acting it is sometimes more convenient to join all the forces into one force which is then called the resultant force.

Comment: Couldn't find my last question's answer.  As well as a intuitive explanation on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...intuitively what actually are components of forces.
>  Are they actual forces.

Define "*actual*".
 If you mean that in a concrete sense, rather than an abstract sense, then no, the components of force are not *actual*.

To see that intuitively, consider components of velocity rather than of force ...
     ... Suppose you're driving 55mph in a northeast direction. Then (spherical geometry complications aside), your components are $v_{\mbox{north}}=55\sin(45^o)\ \mbox{mph}$,   and  $v_{\mbox{east}}=55\cos(45^o)\ \mbox{mph}$.
         But is there any concrete   **>>actual car<<**   moving directly north at 38.89mph, or any actual car moving directly east??? Of course not! You won't get run over standing directly north or directly east of the car's initial position. 
         $v_{\mbox{north}},v_{\mbox{east}}$ are just abstract mathematical conveniences characterizing your car's northeast motion.

Answer (score 0):

The components of a force along the standard axes can be explained simply by this: if you apply forces which are equal in magnitude and in the same direction as each of the components, then the resultant force will be the force of which the components you've found out.

On the standard axes, the components of a force cannot have any components,  as the axes are orthogonal or perpendicular to each other. So, they'll cross out as $\cos (\pi /2) =0$.